# Azure Maps - Can I get the speed limit of the roads?

Tags: azure, bing-maps, azure-maps

I'm trying to get the speed limit of a specific point on the map (lat, lng) using an API, but I can't find it in the Azure Maps documentation. I found it on Bing Maps, but I wanted to use Azure Maps instead if possible, as they give you 250k map free requests per month.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can access speed limit data in Azure Maps by using the reverse geocoding service and setting the "returnSpeedLimit" parameter to true: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressreverse

You can also use the batch reverse geocoding service if you have a lot of data points: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/postsearchaddressreversebatch

You might also find the Traffic flow segment API interesting. It will tell you current speed of traffic on a section of road: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic/gettrafficflowsegment The free flow speed isn't the speed limit, but the average speed vehicles travel that section of road when there is no traffic.

Similarly, the routing service can return the current speed due to traffic over each segment of a route if you set the "sectionType" parameter to "traffic". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/getroutedirections

Comment: Thanks, man! I spent the whole day trying to find anything about the speed limit but the documentation is quite confusing.